# Changing a wav's file format

Tags: audio, music

Does anyone know of some software to convert a wav´s file format? I need to generate wav files with the following format:

format: PCM_UNSIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame

thanks

Comment: probably belongs on superuser.com, not here.

Comment: I presume you already have them in some other format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) (better for batch processing), [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) (if you really want a GUI).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows XP the Sound Recorder application that comes with the OS can convert wav files between different formats. Sadly, the versions that come with Windows Vista and 7 do not have this feature.